# Gorm проблема с вытягиванием связей n+1 или IN()

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, golang, orm

Мне нужно получить список всех компаний и всех электронных почт для них. 
Есть такие структуры:

```
type Company struct {
    Id                  int
    Name                string
    Emails              []CompanyEmail   `gorm:"ForeignKey:idcompany"`
}

type CompanyEmail struct {
    Id        int    `gorm:"index"`
    IdCompany int    `gorm:"column:idcompany"`
    Email     string `gorm:"column:email"`
}
```

Я нашел 2 способа:

**1 - получить весь список компаний а потом пробежаться по нему и получить связи. Тут возникает проблема с N + 1, т.е. возникает проблема с множеством запросов.**

```
companies := []Company{}
db.Find(&companies)
for i, _ := range companies {
    db.Model(companies[i]).Related(&companies[i].Emails, "idcompany")
}
```

**2 - Использовать Preload, но тут возникает проблема с IN(). Мы используем базу данных MSSQL и там есть ограничение для IN() - не больше ~2000 элементов.**

```
companies := []Company{}
db.Preload("Emails").Find(&companies)
```

Не один из способов мне не подходит, подскажите есть ли какое нибудь элегантное решение данной проблемы методами [gorm](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/)?